# WPF SQLite Datagrid grouping

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sqlite, datagrid

I have some information Binding from SQLite local database
and want to show on a Data Grid and group on one of the field

```
<Grid>
  <DataGrid x:Name="elGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Height="356" Width="272" Margin="29,31,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is the .xmla.vb

```
Private Sub loadData()
    Dim a As String = ""
    SetConn()
    sql_con.Open()
    Dim CommandText As String = "select Cname,CMid from conn"
    db = New SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con)
    db.Fill(dt)
    a = dt.Rows.Count.ToString

    elGrid.DataContext = dt

    sql_con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you add group by to the command text? you can also use parameterized queries if you do not want to hard- code the string.

Comment: i don't understand.Could you explain it with reference to the data in db & how you want it in datagrid

Comment: Can you update the question instead, I think there some formatting issues in comments.

Comment: Lets see if looks correctly


MODELO    CONNECTOR       PIN
  1                       A01                 01
                                                  02
                           A02                 01
  2                       B01                 01
                           B02                 01
                                                  02

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if looks correctly

```
MODELO    CONNECTOR       PIN
  1         A01           01
                          02
            A02           01
  2         B01           01
            B02           01
                          02
```